# Can't create a self-referencing relationship on Quote in Dynamics V9 on-prem

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have encountered this issue today when adding a new field of type Lookup on an entity Quote, so it means that it's a self-referencing relationship, but the error I'm getting looks like this:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
> 'QuoteBase' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
> 'prefix_quote_quote_relatedquoteid'.

Then I tried to manually add the relationship, but it changed nothing. I searched the web for answers but so far I can't even find a clue.

Have you experienced such issue before ? What was the remedy ?

Comment: Can you confirm the version, you said v9 then tagged 2016 but the error says Quotebase - this naming convention was there before 2013 I believe. Did you reach out to Microsoft support ?

Comment: @ArunVinoth-PrecogTech-MVP The exact version that's displayed in Deployment Manager is: 9.0.0009.0004 . No, I have not reached out to Microsoft Support.